# Mix static text and scope's variable inside directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a simple form with a name:

```
<form novalidate ng-controller="TestController" role="form" name="testForm">
    <input type="number" min="10" name="textForm" value="4">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="validate(testForm)">
</form>
```

and then I've created a controller:

```
angular.module("testModule", []).controller("TestController", function($scope){     
  $scope.validate = function(form){
      alert("inside the function validate()");
  }
});
```

This works correctly (since the alert pop up on screen) as you can see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/c4EWDRAek5bupHAcUIPD?p=preview).

Now I've added a variable to the scope `$scope.testNumber = 5;` and appended this version to the form's name `name="testForm{{testNumber}}">`and do the same thing on the input submit of the form `<input type="submit" ng-click="validate(testForm{{testNumber}})">`. And this doesn't work, since I can't see any alert, as you can see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/dTQ4nI75xATfrx8jkThr?p=preview). The syntax is not correct, but how can achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 2):

Since your `ng-click` is a function with a param, you need to concat the variables. So `testForm + testnumber` should give you the desired result.

Controller

```
angular.module("testModule", []).controller("TestController", function($scope){
  $scope.testNumber = 5;
  $scope.validate = function(form){
      alert("inside the function validate()" + form);
  }
});
```

Html

```
<form novalidate ng-controller="TestController" role="form" name="testForm{{testNumber}}">
    <input type="number" min="10" name="textForm" value="4">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="validate(testForm + testNumber)"> 
  </form>
```

And a [plunker to demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bWIe6SdZRb0MJxKm8LpP?p=preview) the changes

Comment: If I attach a debugger to your plunk the parameter form is equal to 5 and contain nothing related to form state! For example if I try to retrieve `form.$invalid` which is one of the property provided by `FormController` I get an `undefined`!!!!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Are you trying to validate something, or are you pasning around variables?

Comment: I want to replicate the functionality of the working example, but in a more dynamic environment (i.e. I would retreieve the validation state of the form)

Comment: But why is your question all about the _testnumber_ variable? Validation is done a little differently, on a phone atm, but will give updated answer later

Answer (score 0):

When you use the name attribute of the `form` element, you are publishing the form instance into the controller scope.

Thus, you will have a property `testForm` which you can access with `$scope.testForm`. ([Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state))

Strictly speaking, you don't have to pass the form to the function that you call when you submit as it is accessible from the scope.

However, if you do wish to carry it out, I suggest that you separate the code from the markup - define a scope property in your controller that will hold the name of the form like so:

```
$scope.myForm = 'testForm1';
```

You can then use this in your markup as:

```
<form name="{{myForm}}">
    ...
    <input type="submit" data-ng-click="validate(myForm)"/>
</form>
```

You can easily create an array of form names and use them in your markup (by indexing them) without having to do string concatenation and cluttering your markup.

Comment: This just send the string `testForm1` to the `validate` function.